# Mosquitto DLL file error when trying to start the broker

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am getting the following error when I try to install Mosquito(32bit) on windows machine.
"**the ordinal 3109 could not be located in the dynamic link library libeay32.dll**"
Even though I have put the dll file in the installation folder. Can any one point where I am going wrong and what is the corrective action.

Answer (score 0):

Check the versions of mosquitto installer, OpenSSL and pthreadVC2. This might help you https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/261